# React - importing css/sass in order

Tags: css, reactjs, import, sass, create-react-app

I'm trying to import my css/sass files in order. Somehow my css gets messed up as my bulma framework imports, overwrites all classes coming later.

```
require("./index.scss");
```

in my index.scss i Import bulma (framerwork) first and after this an entryPoint.scss which imports other sass/css files from the assets directory.

```
@import '~bulma/bulma';
@import 'app/assets/sass/entryPoint.scss';
```

and my entryPoint.scss

```
@import "helper/_helper.scss";
@import "helper/_spacing.scss";
@import "global/global.scss";
```

Somehow later imported classes are overwritten my the main classes imported by bulma in my index.scss. All classes in "helper" are overwritten by the main classes in the bulma framework.

Any ideas? I'm using the create-react-app npm script.

Answer (score 0):

What classes are being overriden? My hunch is that you are trying to compete with Bulma classes that are marked with the important rule. If you intend to override these classes in a later file, you will likewise have to mark them as `!important`. That being sad, I would avoid throwing around the important rule unless absolutely necessary as it is easy to misuse.

In your case, I would try the following:

**index.scss**

```
@import "../node_modules/bulma/bulma";
@import "./helpers";
```

**helpers.scss**

```
.is-marginless {
  margin: 3em !important;
}
```